# How do I create objects with enum types for fields

Tags: java, enums

I'm working on a set game program for school.  I have the following constructor for cards:

```
  public SetCard(Colors c, Shapes sp, Shading sd, Numbers num)
  {
     this.color = c;
     this.shape = sp;
     this.shade = sd;
     this.number = num;
  }
```

I am trying to create a deck constructor which makes card with each combination of the four enum types:

```
public setDeck()
{  
  ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>(CARDS_IN_DECK);

  for (Colors c : Colors.values()) {
     for (Shapes sp : Shapes.values()) {
        for (Shading sd : Shading.values()) {
           for (Numbers num : Numbers.values()) {
           cards.add(new SetCard(c, sp, sd, num));
           }
        }   
     }  
  }
return cards;
}
```

When I compile I get an error telling me "constructor SetCard in class SetCard cannot be applied to given types"

My SetCard constructor takes in enum types for arguments so I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: That’s not a constructor, it’s a method. Remove the word void and it might work

Comment: Seems that you should remove `void` from the method `SetCard` to make it a constructor?

Comment: You probably didn't want to edit it out of the *question* - now your question makes no sense.  (Unless you're still getting the same error even after making this change.)

Comment: You'll also need to put the `void` back on `setDeck()` since that's a method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `void` keyword from your constructor, so that it looks like this:

```
 public SetCard(Colors c, Shapes sp, Shading sd, Numbers num)
```

Constructors don't have return types.